# Partisans interest - meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/al-qaeda-chief-urges-westerner-kidnappings-prisoner-exchanges-114335980.html

> "The Ummah (Muslim world) must support this jihad with all that it can, and the mujahideen (Islamist militants) must unite around the word of Tawhid (unity)," said Zawahiri, an Egyptian-born doctor.
>
> "So everyone should prioritize the interest of Islam and the Ummah over his organizational or **partisans interest**, even if he gives up for his brothers what he sees as right."

What does **partisans interest** mean?

Comment: [partisan](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/partisan?q=partisan).

Comment: It is a typo or a misspoken word. It is *partisan interest(s)*, which is a familiar enough concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a typo for **[partisan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/partisan#Noun) interest**. A "partisan interest" is an interest that derives from one's affiliation with a party or faction.

In this context, the sentence you've quoted is basically saying that Muslims should prioritize the interests of Islam as a whole over the interests of subgroups of Islam or other factions (e.g. the interests of Shias, Sunnis, Afghans, Arabs, etc.).